# How to handle an array of Strings in c

Tags: c

I have written a c program which is passed `*input` as parameter and should act as a shell. Thus, I need to split input into an array of strings which I am aiming to do in `char * tokens`. However, e.g. token+2 does not seem to refer to the whole String which I wanted to save at the second position in the array. Could you help me how I would need to change it? Thank you!

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int parse(char *input)
{   
    char * tokens = (char *) malloc(1024);
    //Zaehler, an welcher aktuellen Stelle im Array tokens das Token ist
    int zaehlertokens=0;
    //zaehler der Stelle im Array input:
    int zaehler=0;
    //Zaehler, welche Stelle im Array input die erste nach einem Leerzeichen war:
    int lastspace=0;
    while(input[zaehler]!='\0')
    {
        //Input durchlaufen und bei Leerzeichen in Elemente aufteilen:
        if(input[zaehler]==' ')
        {
            //Alle Buchstaben seit letzem Leerzeichen als neuen Eintrag in tokens speichern:
            strncpy (tokens+zaehlertokens, input+lastspace, zaehler-lastspace-1);

            zaehlertokens++;
            lastspace=zaehler;
            //damit umgehen, dass mehrere Leerzeichen nacheinander kommen:
            while(input[zaehler]==' ')
            {
                zaehler++;
                lastspace++;
                printf("Leerzeichen. Zaehler: %i, Lastspace: %i\n", zaehler, lastspace);
            }
        }
        //Zeiger auf das naechste Element im input Array
        zaehler++;
    }
    //Wenn \0 aufgetreten ist, muss das letzte Elemente noch als token gespeichert werden:
    if(input[zaehler]=='\0')
    {
        //Alle Buchstaben seit letzem Leerzeichen als neuen Eintrag in tokens speichern:
        strncpy (tokens+zaehlertokens, input+lastspace, zaehler-lastspace-1);
        zaehlertokens++;
        lastspace=zaehler;
    }

    int zaehlerAusgabe=0;
    ///Schleife, die die Befehle nacheinander ausgibt
    printf("Vor Ausgabe. Zaehlertokens: %i\n", zaehlertokens);
    while(zaehlerAusgabe<zaehlertokens)
    {
        //row number:token
        printf("%i: %s\n", zaehlerAusgabe, tokens+zaehlerAusgabe, sizeof(zaehlerAusgabe)+1+sizeof(tokens+zaehlerAusgabe));
        fflush(stdout);
        zaehlerAusgabe++;
        //Ueberpruefen, ob exit eingegeben wurde:
        printf("Comparison with exit, %s\n", tokens+zaehlerAusgabe-2 /*-1?*/);
        if(strcmp(tokens+zaehlerAusgabe-1, "exit")==0)
        {
            printf("exit\n");
            exiteingegeben=1;
        }
    }
    return exiteingegeben;
}
```

Comment: Please try using English identifiers and comments, you will reach wider audience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an array of strings you need a 2D array. Initially you can allocate it to a known number of tokens and `realloc` if required.

```
char ** tokens = malloc(noTokens * sizeof(char*));
```

Then you need to allocate memory for each token.

```
// Replace below line with
// strncpy (tokens+zaehlertokens, input+lastspace, zaehler-lastspace-1);

tokens[zaehlertokens] = malloc(zaehler + 1);
strncpy (tokens[zaehlertokens], input+lastspace, zaehler-lastspace-1);
tokens[zaehlertokens][zaehler] = '\0';  // null termination
```

If the memory initially allocated is not enough, you can reallocate it

```
if (zaehlertokens >= noTokens)
{
    noTokens *= 2;
    char ** tokens = realloc(noTokens * sizeof(char*));
}
```